# RLC/diode/MOSFET current measurements in simulink

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, simulink

I designed the following closed-loop boost-buck converter in simulink:

[image]

Just for the sake of clarity, the power stage looks like this:

[image]

I want to measure (and display on an oscilloscope) the current through various components of the power stage without placing ammeters in the circuit, as the ammeters will just mess up the circuit.

To do so, I used the "extra" terminal in the diodes and connected them to the scope, as you can see in the screenshot above. And to measure the current through the inductor L1 (the reference designators are far away from the components for some reason), I double-clicked on it and selected the "branch current measurement" option.

[image]

After running the simulation, I double-clicked on the scope block to see the diode current measurements. This is what I saw:

[image]

Upon zooming in, I saw this:

[image]

Both the voltage across the diodes and the current through the diodes are plotted on the same graph. This makes it quite hard to properly see the current waveform. I'm unable to isolate the current waveform and scale it to occupy the full vertical space.

I googled [measurement of diode current matlab](https://www.google.com/search?q=measurement+of+diode+current+matlab&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN826IN826&oq=measurem&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0i433i512j69i57j0i433i512l2j69i60l3.3512j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but that didn't bring up any useful articles.

This brings us to the first question - is there a way to disable either the current or voltage waveform so that I can just view the one that I want?

After closing the scope, I tried to view the current waveform through the inductor L1. I tried clicking on the component (as I do in LTspice) to view the current through it, but it didn't work. I had selected the "branch current" measurement option, so I expected the waveform to pop up on its own or appear when I clicked on the component, but it didn't.

And this brings us to the second question - after selecting "branch current" in the measurement menu, how do I view it?

---

Edit: I found how to view [branch current on a multimeter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/seriesrlcbranch.html). Connecting the multimeter to the scope gives the instantaneous current.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bus ripper to break out the signals to plot to individual scopes.

Depending on your version of Matlab you can also configure the scope to have multiple subplots corresponding to signal channels

Comment: Could you please tell me where I can find this bus ripper?